# Win CE Enable/Disable Touch With Application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, embedded, windows-mobile, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6

I'm working on a Embedded device that running Win CE 6.0.

With visual studio 2008, I've created my own c# application for this Windows.

My application is ok but my problem is the touch screen of this device.

The Touch Screen of this device only works with the manufacturer application and as soon as the application closes, the touch will stop working too!
And again when I open it, the touch works very well!
I have 2 applications from this manufacturer and both of them easily can enable and disable the touch.

The Calibration of the touch is ok in the registry.[Machine/Hardware/Devicemap/Touch]

Can someone explain me how is that works?

I Want to Enable the Touch with my own c# application.

Comment: Hello, you may try http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/09/24/windows-mobile-disable-touch-input/. Possibly the manufactorer uses a OEM function and provide a SDK for the device to enable/disable the touch screen?!

Comment: Thanks you. I've done it before. Not works! / i have the touch.dll file in my windows folder but when I Import and use TouchRegister or TouchUnregister function, my application stops and gives me error : can't find PInvoke dll touch.dll

Comment: Then you have an error in how you use PInvoke. Either the touch.dll does not export the functions (can be checked with PEInfo for CE) or you have a mistake in the .NET code using the DLLImport. You may also analyse or decompile the "manufacturer application" to find out what their code does.

Comment: I may help more, if you send me a link to the apps and name the manufactorer and model of the device